# workload identity can work 2 different GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

ON GCP,I need to use 2 GCP project; One is for web-application, the other is for storing secrets for web-application ( which structure comes from [google's repository](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-example-foundation#secrets)

As written in README, I'll store secrets using [GCP Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager)

> This project is allocated for GCP Secret Manager for secrets shared by the organization.

#### procedure I'm planning

1. **prj-secret** : create secrets in secrets-manager
2. **prj-application** : read secret using [kubernetes-external-secrets](https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets)

in **prj-application** I want to use [workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) , because I don't want to use as serviceaccountkey [doc saying](https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets#deploy-kubernetes-external-secrets-using-a-service-account-key)

#### What I did

1. create cluser with `-workload-pool=project-id.svc.id.goog` option
2. helm install kubernetes-external-secrets
3. [skip] kubectl create namespace k8s-namespace ( because I install kubernetes-external-secrets on `default` name space)
4. [skip] kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace k8s-namespace ksa-name ( because I use `default` serviceaccount with exist by default when creating GKE)
5. create google-service-account with `module "workload-identity`

```
module "workload-identity" {
   source               = "github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine//modules/workload-identity"
   use_existing_k8s_sa  = true
   cluster_name         = var.cluster_name
   location             = var.cluter_locaton
   k8s_sa_name          = "external-secrets-kubernetes-external-secrets"
   name                 = "external-secrets-kubernetes"
   roles                = ["roles/secretmanager.admin","roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"]
   project_id           = var.project_id  #it is prj-aplication's project_id
}
```

- kubernetes_serviceaccount called `external-secrets-kubernetes-external-secrets` was already created when installing `kubernetes-external-secrets` with helm. and it bind k8s_sa_name &' external-secrets-kubernetes@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com, which has ["roles/secretmanager.admin","roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"].

6. create externalsecret and apply

```
apiVersion: kubernetes-client.io/v1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: external-key-test
spec:
  backendType: gcpSecretsManager
  projectId: my-domain
  data:
    - key: key-test
      name: password
```

#### result

I got permission problem

> ERROR, 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource 'projects/project-id/secrets/external-key-test/versions/latest' (or it may not exist).

I already checked that, if I  **prj-secret** and **prj-application** is same project, it worked.

So what I thought is,
kubernetes serviceaccount (in **prj-secret**) & google serviceaccount (in **prj-application**) cannot bind correctly.

I wonder if someone know

- workload-identity works only in same project or not
- if it is, how can I get secret data from different project

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue in your role binding I think. When you say this:

> kubernetes_serviceaccount called external-secrets-kubernetes-external-secrets was already created when installing kubernetes-external-secrets with helm. and it bind k8s_sa_name &' external-secrets-kubernetes@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com, which has ["roles/secretmanager.admin","roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"].

It's unclear.

1. `external-secrets-kubernetes@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com,` is created on which project? I guess in prj-application, but not clear.

---

2. I take the assumption (with the name and the link with the cluster) that the service account is created in the prj-application. you grant the role `"roles/secretmanager.admin","roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"` on which resource?

- On the IAM page of the prj-application?
- On the IAM page of the prj-secret?
- On the secretId of the secret in the prj-secret?

If you did the 1st one, it's the wrong binding, the service account can only access to the secret of the prj-application, and not these of prj-secret.

*Note, if you only need to access the secret, don't grand the admin role, only the accessor is required.*